# Merge sort in java and copying array, still nlogn?

Tags: java, mergesort

I've taken a look at a few implementations of merge sort in java, and it seems like the splitting part is commonly done by creating 2 new arrays, left and right and copying the left and right parts to those arrays respectively.

My question is: This still gives us nlogn time right? Because now each split would have n+n time (n time for splitting the array, n time for merging the array) and there are logn splits, so we have 2nlogn which is still nlogn. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. O(2n logn) is still O(n logn).

Comment: Plus, array division happens in-place. not new array per se.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a in-place array division, but it kind of seems messy. You'll need to keep track of a start and end index of your original array right? It doesn't seem too hard to implement but it definitely seems like there's more places for error than if you just create a new left and a new right array.

Comment: @Kevin I understand. But that's what is called optimization.

Comment: It's a shame that mainstream languages don't have array slices [D Slices](https://dlang.org/d-array-article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Which implementations were you looking at? The primary sorting algorithms used by the JDK are [`DualPivotQuicksort`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java) (for primitive arrays), [`TimSort`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java) and [`ComparableTimSort`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ComparableTimSort.java) (for `Object` arrays/collections), and the incomprehensible wizardy in [`ArraysParallelSortHelpers`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArraysParallelSortHelpers.java) for concurrent sorts.

All of these classes provide highly-tuned implementations of QuickSort or MergeSort (or in the parallel case ["CilkSort"](http://supertech.lcs.mit.edu/cilk/), which sounds like a concurrency-friendly MergeSort). These algorithms are all generally O(n log(n)) - it's [impossible to do better than O(n log(n))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) without additional constraints on your inputs.

As to whether these algorithms generally spend O(n) time copying values back-and-forth between temporary storage, it's very much a case-by-case question. Where possible these implementations will certainly try to avoid using O(n) extra memory and time to do linear copying, but oftentimes such work is not actually the bottleneck. For example CilkSort uses a secondary "workspace array" to copy values back and forth from in successive stages, which makes it easier to enforce invariants since the "prior" stage is always in a reliable state. Even so the implementations try to avoid unnecessary array-copies whenever possible.

At the public API level we'll notice that `Collections.sort()` calls `.toArray()`, sorts the array, and then copies the values back into the original `List`. This is similarly just a practical optimization - it's faster to sort an array and do two linear copies than to deal with all the method invocations (and potentially inefficient `List` implementations, such as `LinkedList`) of modifying the `List` in-place.